# Run android 4.2.2 build target application in android 4.4.2

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm currently developing an android application. in manifest i have put the minSkdVersion and targetSdk version as follows.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

when i'm trying to run the application in android 4.4.2 nexus 4 phone it shown unknown target in select device dialog screen as following

is it not possible to run on android higher version with less api build target.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run your app on a device with API version less than the build version. The minimum API you can run on is decided by `android:minSdkVersion` attribute.

You have a problem with connecting your device properly. Please note that it is listed as offline. The device status/unavailability has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: initiallly i have enabled the usb debugging. but I re-install the driver and connect it. then they ask me again to enable usb-debugging. I allowed it and now its working.